# The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Person>() .Where(p => p.Id % 2 == 0 ? Even : Odd == Even)' could not be translated

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a class person, which has some aggregated values, e.g. if the Id is Even or Odd.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ... some properties
    public static Expression<Func<Person, NumberType>> NumberType
    {
        get
        {
            return p => ((p.Id % 2 == 0)
                ? Shared.NumberType.Even
                : Shared.NumberType.Odd);
        }
    }
}

public enum NumberType
{
    Even = 0,
    Odd = 1
}
```

Now If I try to get my people with even ids

```
// this is DbSet<Person>
var people = dbContext.People.AsQueryable();

// this alone works
people = people.Where(p => ((p.Id % 2 == 0) ? Shared.NumberType.Even : Shared.NumberType.Odd) == Shared.NumberType.Even);

// this should do exactly the same as above but results in the following error as soon as the queryable is evaluated
var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, Person.LocalNumberType.Body, Expression.Constant(Shared.NumberType.Even));
people =  people.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(body, Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "p")));


// exception thrown here
var evenCount = people.Count();
```

[image]
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
.Where(p => (int)p.Id % 2 == 0 ? Even : Odd == 0)
.Where(p => p.Id % 2 == 0 ? Even : Odd == Even)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

```
// FUNFACT, ordering by the Expression works
var orderByExp = (typeof(Person).GetProperty("NumberType")!.GetValue(null, null) as LambdaExpression);
people = people.Provider.CreateQuery<Person>(Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "orderBy",
    new Type[] {
        typeof(Person),
        orderByExp.ReturnType
    },
    people.Expression,
    Expression.Quote(orderByExp)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter expressions inside lambda expressions are identified by instance, not by name as you seem to think. So here

```cs
var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, Person.LocalNumberType.Body, Expression.Constant(Shared.NumberType.Even));
people =  people.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(body, Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "p")));
```

the body is bound to the source `Person.NumberType` expression parameter, but then you are using it inside new lambda expression with *different* parameter (event though it is the same type and name).

One possible solution is to reuse the original parameter, e.g.

```cs
var source = Person.LocalNumberType;
var body = Expression.Equal(source.Body, Expression.Constant(Shared.NumberType.Even));
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(body, source.Parameters);

people =  people.Where(predicate);
```